# Cloning empty repository

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to clone my Heroku repository, but when I run

`heroku git:clone -a myservername`

I get the error:

> warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

Comment: or simply add one small file that you later delete, or better yet a `.gitignore`. Really, *you're just trying to swim against the current here* :)

Answer (score 4):

It is normal to get the warning the first time we create a new repository. Don't worry about that, proceed with your first commit and push it to your server.

Comment: Ok. I need to make some changes to the index.js file. But I cannot find it in the cloned serverfolder. How can I find the index.js?

Comment: Do you make any push? Until you make a push after a commit, this file will not be find in the server

Comment: After some trouble I have made a push. Where should I be able to find the Index.js? The only Index file is in `myapp/.git` and that don't seem right.

Comment: Forget .git folder,  it's for internal use of git. You have to write your index.js file, commit it and push the repository to the sever. Then you can clone the repository in other computer and index.js will appear there. Please ask me any question and check and vote the answer. Thanks!